# Changing Google Groups email from script throws Invalid Value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-groups, google-groups-api

Being a super admin of my school's Google Workspace domain, I'd like to change Google Groups emails with a script. The following minimal script does his job changing the Name of the group:

```
function GroupUpd() {
  var OldEmail = '1z_22-23@abc.edu.it';
  var NewEmail = '2z_22-23@abc.edu.it';
  var NewName = "2Z";

  var group = AdminGroupsSettings.Groups.get(OldEmail);

  group.name=NewName;
  AdminGroupsSettings.Groups.patch(group, OldEmail);
}
```

Instead if I try to change the group email this code

```
function GroupUpd() {
  var OldEmail = '1z_22-23@abc.com';
  var NewEmail = '2z_22-23@abc.com';
  var NewName = "2Z";

  var group = AdminGroupsSettings.Groups.get(OldEmail);

  group.email=NewEmail;
  AdminGroupsSettings.Groups.patch(group, OldEmail);
}
```

gives:

> GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to groupsSettings.groups.patch failed with error: Invalid Value

The very same happens if I use

```
AdminGroupsSettings.Groups.patch(group, OldEmail);
```

So, it seems to be a problem with `NewEmail`, but I have no idea what I am supposed to change.

DISCLAIMER: I'm a noob.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Saying "It doesn't work" [is frowned upon](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) upon on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you, I'm new to this, hopefully now it is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead Groups Settings API use the Directory API.

References

- https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/groups-settings/v1/reference/groups/update
- https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/groups-settings/v1/reference/groups#json